# How to get the number of symbols in a SymPy expression

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to get the number of symbols in a SymPy expression like:

```
a = sympify('1/4*x+y+c+1/2')
```

The number for instance should be `3`.  All I came up with so far is

```
a.args.__len__()
```

However, this counts also the constant factors 1/4 and 1/2.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [**`atoms`**](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/core.html?highlight=atoms#sympy.core.basic.Basic.atoms) method  to get a list with all symbols in an expression.

```
In [32]: a.atoms(Symbol)
Out[32]: {c, x, y}
```